# How to match objects based on selected manytomany in Django orm

Tags: django, django-orm

Im trying to get objects based on selected/added items in a ManyToMany field.

My models:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class BenefitLocation(models.Model):
  benefit = models.ForeignKey(Benefit)
  location = models.ForeignKey(Location)

class Benefit(models.Model):
    locations = models.ManyToManyField(Location, through='BenefitLocation')
```

Here is what Im trying to do in the orm:

```
selected_locations = Location.objects.filter(id__in[1,2]) #Getting IDs from api request

matching_benefits = Benefit.objects.filter(locations=selected_locations)
```

In matching_benefits, I only want those with exactly these selected locations. When I try my code, I get this error: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')`

How can I get the matching_benefits?

**Edit:**

Using @Willem Van Onsem code like this:

```
location_ids = [1]
location_ids = set(location_ids)

matching_benefits = Benefit.objects.annotate(
  nloc_count=Count('locations'),
  nloc_filter=Count('locations', filter=Q(locations__in=location_ids))
  ).filter(
  nloc_count=len(location_ids),
  nloc_filter=len(location_ids)
)

for item in matching_benefits:
  print(item.locations.values('id'))
  
#output
#<QuerySet [{'id': 1}]>
#<QuerySet [{'id': 2}]>
```

But the query still gives two benefits (with different locations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an `__in`:

```
selected_locations = Location.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2])
matching_benefits = Benefit.objects.filter(locations__in=selected_locations)
```

but here it is cleaner to use the list of ids directly:

```
matching_benefits = Benefit.objects.filter(locations__in=[1,2])
```

If you are looking for `Benefit`s that have *at least* all these locations, you filter with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

location_ids = [1, 2]
location_ids = set(location_ids)

matching_benefits = Benefit.objects.filter(
    locations__in=location_ids
).annotate(nloc=Count('locations')).filter(nloc=len(location_ids))
```

For `Benefit`s that have *exactly* all these locations, you filter with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Q

location_ids = [1,2]
location_ids = set(location_ids)

matching_benefits = Benefit.objects.annotate(
    nloc=Count('locations'),
    nloc_filter=Count('locations', filter=Q(locations__in=location_ids))
).filter(
    nloc=len(location_ids),
    nloc_filter=len(location_ids)
)
```

Comment: Using `__in` does not seem like the filter gets specific benefits with exact location_id in locations. The filter gets benefits with just one of the location_id in the list.

Comment: @TomasJacobsen: I'm not entirely following what you are saying. It will use an `IN ...` clause to fetch the objects. In case you use `selected_locations`, it will use a subquery. For MySQL databases, this is often a problem, since MySQL does not analyzes the subquery to see it is "*static*", and it will thus run the subquery for every element.

Comment: Lets say there are two locations `New York` and `London`, and there are three benefits. One with just `New York`, one with `London` and the third one with both locations. If I do `__in` to check which benefit that has the location of "`London` && `New York`" I will get all three of the benefits, but I only wanted to get the one where both of the locations were present.

Comment: @TomasJacobsen: if there is a benfit with `New York`, `London` and `Paris`, should that be included as well?

Comment: No, if the filter asks for `New York` and `London`, it should only retrieve the benefit(s) that has exactly those selected.

Comment: @TomasJacobsen: then it is the last code fragment, see edit.

Comment: Sorry, still getting too many benefits in the query, if I try to only get a benefit with one specific location. Then I get all the benefits with one location, not exactly the location Im querying for.

Comment: @TomasJacobsen: but you are using the `filter=Q(locations__in=location_ids)` part in the `Count(..)`? What is the Django version, this has been added since 2.0 If I recall correctly.

Comment: Ah, I'm still on **1.11**, maybe I need to to an extra forloop to get the correct one, until I upgrade django.

Comment: @TomasJacobsen: no, there are no loops involved here. The problem is that you can not filter on the aggregate before Django-2.0. I would strongly advice to upgrade, since 1.11 is not supported anymore since 2018 if I recall correctly.